# Triggering UltiSnips in command-line mode

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

Is there a way to expand a UltiSnips snippet while in vim command-line mode? I can only expand a snippet in insert mode.

I am using UltiSnips to help inserting unicode characters. And I need to write these characters in the command-line for searching. I do not want to insert them using `<C-v>u`. I also prefer not to use digraphs.

Comment: Digraphs are made exactly for this purpose (IMO using snippets is a bit overkill to insert a single character). Why don't you want to use them?

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't achieve to trigger the completion from the command-line mode you can work this like this :

Prepare your command inside insert mode (or at least the part you cannot create from command-line mode). Yank it and insert it inside your command using `<C-r>` and the `"` register like so :

Insert Mode

```
tec<Tab>yiw
```

Commande-line Mode

```
:/<C-r>"
```

In command-line mode, there are only a set of word you can expand, for example : Command names, Tags, File names, ...

See : http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-completion

Comment: I don't know how to use your answer, can you explain it further, please? 

E.g. I have a snippet `ec` that expands to `ê` and I use `<Tab>` key to expand snippets.

In insert mode, I type
`tec<Tab>`
and get
`tê`.

In command-line mode to search, I type
`/tec<Tab>`
but get nothing.

How do I use this `:call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()`?

Comment: Oh ok I didn't understand your question, let me update my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The mapping

```
cnoremap {lhs} <C-r>=&cedit<CR>:call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR><C-c>
```

maps {lhs} to expand a (simple) snippet in the command line.

Here's what the {rhs} of the mapping does:

```
<C-r>=&cedit<CR>                                         switch to the command line window (Typically evaluates to <C-f>)
                :call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>      expand the snippet
                                                   <C-c> switch back to the command line
```

An UltiSnips snippet cannot be expanded in the command line. However, the command line *window*, being a "standard" buffer, allows snippets to be expanded within.

For simple snippets with no placeholder texts, this mapping works as intended.

---

However, if a snippet contains multiple tabstops, the user is unable to jump beyond the first tabstop. Also, if a tabstop contains placeholder text, it is not overwritten upon further typing. One possible explanation is that after `<C-c>` is pressed, the command line window is "forgotten", and along with it, the tabstops' locations.

A workaround is to remain in the command line window, instead of going back to the command line. (ie., remove `<C-c>` in the mapping above). Then, placeholder texts are correctly overwritten upon typing, and the user can jump between tabstops as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I use `noreabbrev` to insert frequently used unicodes, for example:

```
noreabbrev vvref ※
noreabbrev vvsec §
```

Abbreviations are triggered automatically on non-keyword character or `CTRL+]`. It works both in Insert Mode and Command Mode. Or use `cnoreabbrev` and `inoreabbrev` to define Command Mode and Insert Mode only abbreviations. It also can be used to [define command aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879737).

More information can be found in `:help abbreviations`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Your answer was flagged for review since it's too short. I do think it could be improved. Could you explain *how* you use `noreabbrev` to insert frequently used Unicode characters? Perhaps some examples of the commands you personally use? That would surely improve this answer... Thanks!